# How do i center text in the terminal in C

Tags: c, terminal, menu, printf

Hi i'd like to know how to center text in C.
For example in this menu how could i center the commands?

```
        printf("\n%s\n", "--------- Command Menu ---------");
        printf("%s\n", "LOAD");
        printf("%s\n", "CLEAR");
        printf("%s\n", "LIST");
        printf("%s\n", "FOUNDP");
        printf("%s\n", "QUIT");
        printf("---------------------------------\n");
```

I want something like this:
[image]

Comment: In pure standard C, you'll have to hack it manually by deciding a width, dividing it in half, then subtract half the string length from that to get the x coordinate. Then pad with spaces until reaching it.

Comment: @Lundin is there a website where i can look into that?

Comment: You need to know basic math, `strlen`, `printf` and loops. Just use common sense from there. Various non-standard libs may have functions like "gotoxy" which lets you print at given coordinates, but you will still have to calculate those coordinates.

Comment: You can print a bunch of spaces before each word. `num_spaces = (total_width - word_length) / 2`

Comment: How are you planning for the user to select an option?

Answer (score 1):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void center(char *s, int n) {
    printf("%*s\n", (n + (int)strlen(s)) / 2, s);
}

int main(void) {
    int n = printf("\n%s\n", "--------- Command Menu ---------") - 2;
    center("LOAD", n);
    center("CLEAR", n);
    center("LIST", n);
    center("FOUNDP", n);
    center("QUIT", n);
    printf("---------------------------------\n");
    return 0;
}
```

You can make this more generic by writing a `cprintf()` function using `vasprintf()`.

Comment: To allow `center()` to work for longer strings, you should test if `strlen(s) > n` and avoid passing a negative argument value oof the `*` as it has a different meaning: `printf("|%*s|", -10, "hello")` outputs `|hello     |`, the same as `printf("|%-*s|", 10, "hello")`

Answer (score 0):

> **This post includes two examples of ways to write this kind of things.**

> **The second one is far more common and generic. Both examples include code and output.**

#### about the code in the question

Sure you can write it this way, but

```
    printf("%s\n", "LOAD");
```

is the same as

```
    printf("LOAD\n");
```

About the code, you may prefer to use

```
    printf("\
\n\
--------- Command Menu ---------\n\
LOAD\n\
CLEAR\n\
LIST\n\
FOUNDP\n\
QUIT\n\
---------------------------------\n");
```

instead of

```
    printf("\n%s\n", "--------- Command Menu ---------");
    printf("%s\n", "LOAD");
    printf("%s\n", "CLEAR");
    printf("%s\n", "LIST");
    printf("%s\n", "FOUNDP");
    printf("%s\n", "QUIT");
    printf("---------------------------------\n");
```

It is far more easier to align and edit. And hundreds of times faster, since it it is a single function call.

### TL:DR; Example "0"

The function used in example 2:

```
char* resize_opt(size_t full_len, const char* opt_text)
{
    if (opt_text == NULL) return NULL;
    size_t opt_len = strlen(opt_text);
    size_t start   = (full_len - opt_len) / 2;
    char*  out     = malloc(1 + start + opt_len);
    if (out == NULL) return NULL;
    size_t i = 0;
    for (; i < (full_len - opt_len) / 2; i += 1)
        out[i] = ' ';
    out[i] = 0;  // terminate string
    strcpy(out + start, opt_text);
    return out;
}
```

can be used as in

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* resize_opt(size_t len, const char* text);

int main(void)
{
    const char header[] = "--------- Command Menu ---------";
    const char* option    = "Stack Overflow";

    char*       test   = resize_opt(sizeof(header), option);
    printf("\t\t%s\n\t\t%s\n", header, test);
    free(test);

    test = resize_opt(sizeof(header), "LOAD");
    printf("\t\t%s\n", test);
    free(test);

    test = resize_opt(sizeof(header), "CLEAR");
    printf("\t\t%s\n", test);
    free(test);

    return 0;
}

char* resize_opt(size_t full_len, const char* opt_text)
{
    if (opt_text == NULL) return NULL;
    size_t opt_len = strlen(opt_text);
    size_t start   = (full_len - opt_len) / 2;
    char*  out     = malloc(1 + start + opt_len);
    if (out == NULL) return NULL;
    size_t i = 0;
    for (; i < (full_len - opt_len) / 2; i += 1)
        out[i] = ' ';
    out[i] = 0;  // terminate string
    strcpy(out + start, opt_text);
    return out;
}
```

and shows

```
                --------- Command Menu ---------
                         Stack Overflow
                              LOAD
                              CLEAR
```

### Example 1

On the other hand, one reason to do it the way you did would to be able to use some formatting on the `%s` clause.

It is clear that you want to center the options based on the size of the title, so you can write

```
    const char title[] = "--------- Command Menu ---------";
    const unsigned t_len   = sizeof(title);  // title len
    const char     op[]    = "LOAD";
    unsigned       opt_len = sizeof(op);
```

and then compute how large the `%s` should be used, as in

```
    unsigned       size = opt_len + (t_len - opt_len) / 2;
    char           spec[30] = {0};
    sprintf(spec, "%%%ds", size);
    printf("specifier is \"%s\"\n", spec);
```

And we see

```
specifier is "%19s"
```

And then use it as

```
    printf("%s\n", title);
    printf(spec, op);
```

And get

```
--------- Command Menu ---------
               LOAD
```

#### Centering an array of options

This example uses such idea. An arrray of options is built as needed

#### output

```
--------- Command Menu ---------

              LOAD

              CLEAR

              LIST

             FOUNDP

              QUIT

--------------------------------
```

#### the `C` Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    const char title[] =  "--------- Command Menu ---------";
    const char ending[] = "--------------------------------";
    const unsigned t_len = sizeof(title);  // title len
    const char*    option[5]   = {
        "LOAD",
        "CLEAR",
        "LIST",
        "FOUNDP",
        "QUIT"
    };
    size_t       opt_len[5] = {0};
    size_t n_opt = sizeof(option) / sizeof(char*);

    printf("%s\n\n", title);
    for (size_t n = 0; n < n_opt; n += 1)
    {
        opt_len[n] = strlen(option[n]);
        size_t size =
            opt_len[n] + (t_len - opt_len[n]) / 2;
        char     spec[30] = {0};
        sprintf(spec, "%%%llus\n\n", size);
        printf(spec, option[n]);
    }
    printf("%s\n", ending);
    return 0;
}
```

### Example 2: some OOP things: writing around the data

It is often more productive to see things as objects an give them properties and data. This example builds a generic menu and uses it to build the same menu as in the original question.

**It is just an example. Add your error conditions and you can run it in any code. Even for any number of `Menu` in your program. No need to rewrite a thing.**

Note that every window in Windows or in any UI framework has a menu included.

#### a *Menu* thing

This a possible menu:

```
typedef struct
{
    char*   title;
    size_t  n_options;
    size_t* opt_len;  // array of sizes
    char**  option;   // array of pointers to options
    char*   ending;
} Menu;
```

We can not go wrong with an array of pointers to `char*` for the menu: every `C` program gets one, since the prototype for `main` is

```
    int main(int argc, char** arg);
```

and it works well still after some decades

#### some *methods* for the `Menu`

Consider

```
    Menu* so_create_menu(
       const char* title, const char* ending,
       const size_t n_options, ...);

    Menu* so_destroy_menu(Menu*);

    int   so_show_menu(Menu*, const char*);
```

The use is as simple as the names suggest: create, destroy and show a menu. This way we can use `Menu` as an entity for itself. These lines in the example code

```
    const char* header = "--------- Command Menu ---------";
    const char* footer = "--------------------------------";

    Menu* one = so_create_menu(
        header, footer, 5, "LOAD", "CLEAR", "LIST",
        "FOUNDP", "QUIT");
```

encapsulate all data in a `Menu` thing and returns its address. It is the same menu provided in the question.

`so_show_menu()` is just for testing, but it is fairly obvious that during development it will be needed so it is the first function to be written.

#### Using a *`Menu`*

The purpose of such a thing is to show the user the options and let the user select one, so it is far more easier to write aroud the `Menu` and have something like

```
        size_t so_get_option(Menu*);
```

And call it as in

```
    size_t my_opt = so_get_option(one);
    printf("\t\tOption was %llu\n", my_opt);
```

And never use any `Menu` option or field in the program code: encapsulation and SRP --- Single Responsibily Principle is a good thing

**Note that the function only returns with a valid option.**

#### `main` for these example

```
    const char* header = "--------- Command Menu ---------";
    const char* footer = "--------------------------------";

    Menu* one = so_create_menu(
        header, footer, 5, "LOAD", "CLEAR", "LIST",
        "FOUNDP", "QUIT");

    so_show_menu(one, "just testing\n\n");

    size_t my_opt = so_get_option(one);
    printf("\t\tOption was %llu\n", my_opt);

    so_destroy_menu(one);
    return 0;
}
```

#### output of the example

```
--------- Command Menu ---------

              LOAD -  1

             CLEAR -  2

              LIST -  3

             FOUNDP -  4

              QUIT -  5


Your Option:_ 42
--------- Command Menu ---------

              LOAD -  1

             CLEAR -  2

              LIST -  3

             FOUNDP -  4

              QUIT -  5


Your Option:_ 2
--------------------------------
                Option was 2

        ** destroying Menu
```

#### how the text ended up centered?

This simple function gets the text for an option and the expected size it will be centered on, and returns the adequate string:

```
char* resize_opt(size_t full_len, const char* opt_text)
{
    if (opt_text == NULL) return NULL;
    size_t opt_len = strlen(opt_text);
    size_t start   = (full_len - opt_len) / 2;
    char*  out     = malloc(1 + start + opt_len);
    if (out == NULL) return NULL;
    size_t i = 0;
    for (; i < (full_len - opt_len) / 2; i += 1)
        out[i] = ' ';
    out[i] = 0;  // terminate string
    strcpy(out + start, opt_text);
    return out;
}
```

Here is the code for insering an adjusted option in the `Menu`:

```
        char* one = resize_opt(
            strlen(M->title), va_arg(args, char*));
        M->option[n] = malloc(1 + strlen(one));
        strcpy(M->option[n], one);
        free(one);
        M->opt_len[n] = strlen(M->option[n]);
```

Instead of using the user provided string for insertion (and get it left aligned) we just get a pointer for the adjusted one for the length we have. Since it will not be used anymore we free it immediately.

#### Complete code for the Example 2

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char*   title;
    size_t  n_options;
    size_t* opt_len;  // array of sizes
    char**  option;   // array of pointers to options
    char*   ending;
} Menu;

Menu* so_create_menu(
    const char* title, const char* ending,
    const size_t n_options, ...);
Menu* so_destroy_menu(Menu*);
int   so_show_menu(Menu*, const char*);

size_t so_get_option(Menu*);

// helper function to center text
char* resize_opt(size_t len, const char* text);

int main(void)
{
    const char* header = "--------- Command Menu ---------";
    const char* footer = "--------------------------------";

    Menu* one = so_create_menu(
        header, footer, 5, "LOAD", "CLEAR", "LIST",
        "FOUNDP", "QUIT");

    so_show_menu(one, "just testing\n\n");

    size_t my_opt = so_get_option(one);
    printf("\t\tOption was %llu\n", my_opt);

    so_destroy_menu(one);
    return 0;
}

Menu* so_create_menu(
    const char* title, const char* ending,
    const size_t n_options, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    Menu*   M = malloc(sizeof(Menu));
    if (M == NULL) return NULL;
    // process title and ending
    M->title = malloc(1 + strlen(title));
    strcpy(M->title, title);
    M->ending = malloc(1 + strlen(ending));
    strcpy(M->ending, ending);
    M->n_options = n_options;
    // allocate required arrays
    M->opt_len = malloc(n_options * sizeof(size_t));
    M->option  = (char**)malloc(n_options * sizeof(char*));
    va_start(args, n_options);
    for (size_t n = 0; n < n_options; n += 1)
    {
        char* one = resize_opt(
            strlen(M->title), va_arg(args, char*));
        M->option[n] = malloc(1 + strlen(one));
        strcpy(M->option[n], one);
        free(one);
        M->opt_len[n] = strlen(M->option[n]);
    };
    va_end(args);
    return M;
}

Menu* so_destroy_menu(Menu* M)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\n\t** destroying Menu\n");
    if (M == NULL) return NULL;
    free(M->title);
    free(M->ending);
    free(M->opt_len);
    for (size_t n = 0; n < M->n_options; n += 1)
        free(M->option[n]);
    free(M->option);
    free(M);
    return NULL;
}

int so_show_menu(Menu* M, const char* msg)
{
    if (M == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "\
\n\
    %llu options in this menu.\n\
\n\
      Title  is \"%s\"\n\
      Ending is \"%s\"\n\
\n\
    Options:\n\
\n",
        M->n_options, M->title, M->ending);
    //
    for (size_t n = 0; n < M->n_options; n += 1)
        printf(
            "\t%llu: \"%s\"\t[%llu]\n", n, M->option[n],
            M->opt_len[n]);
    printf("[...]\n");
    return 0;
}

size_t so_get_option(Menu* M)
{
    int option = 0;
    do {
        printf("%s\n\n", M->title);
        for (size_t n = 0; n < M->n_options; n += 1)
            printf("%s - %2llu\n\n", M->option[n], 1 + n);
        printf("\nYour Option:_ ");
        char   line[200];
        char*  p   = fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        size_t opt = atoi(line);
        if (opt <= M->n_options)
        {
            printf("%s\n", M->ending);
            return opt;
        }
    } while (1);
    return 0;
}

char* resize_opt(size_t full_len, const char* opt_text)
{
    if (opt_text == NULL) return NULL;
    size_t opt_len = strlen(opt_text);
    size_t start   = (full_len - opt_len) / 2;
    char*  out     = malloc(1 + start + opt_len);
    if (out == NULL) return NULL;
    size_t i = 0;
    for (; i < (full_len - opt_len) / 2; i += 1)
        out[i] = ' ';
    out[i] = 0;  // terminate string
    strcpy(out + start, opt_text);
    return out;
}
```